# Redmi Note 5 Pro - unable to flash TWRP

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, fastboot, xiaomi, redmi

I am trying to flash the LineageOS on my Redmi Note 5 Pro (*whyred*). Initially, I used Windows 10 for the Xiaomi Unlock Tool. However, the Xiaomi Unlock Tool did not detect my device. So, I used this tool https://www.xiaomitool.com/V2/ to unlock my bootloader and it unlocked instantly.
Now, I am using Ubuntu 21.04 (I am more comfortable using the command line here) (with android-tools-adb and android-tools-fastboot packages installed) to try to flash TWRP first.

When I connect my device, `adb devices` can recognise it. Then I use `adb reboot bootloader` to enter into fastboot. Now, `fastboot devices` can recognise it too. The screen of the phone shows the fastboot icon.

But, the problem comes here. I use `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` and I get this error

> FAILED (Write to device failed (No such device))

Now, when I use `fastboot devices` again. I don't see my device. Another change I see is **press any key to shutdown** written on the top left corner of the screen of my phone.

USB debugging, USB debugging security, OEM debugging are all enabled. Bootloader is unlocked (as I see in the settings). The phone is updated to latest MIUI version supported officially. And I used the same laptop and method to flash TWRP in a Redmi 3S (*land*) some time back.

Comment: Something else I experienced is that after randomly trying to get this right again and again, the command ```fastboot flash recovery twrp.img``` did not terminate and got stuck.

Comment: Well, I didn't really understand what happened. But there's this concept of Anti-roll-back due to which I was unable to flash TWRP. I followed the 5th method here and it worked. https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/everything-about-anti-roll-back-whyred.3816219/